# Close function not working in Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to close a pop-up DIV using a closing function with jquery, It worked before I added the position function of the DIV, and something I did must have broken the function... I'm guessing it's a syntax error somewhere, any fresh pair of eyes out there willing to take a look?

Thw working site is at www.masterfade.com/maptest

Here's the code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $('.lightbox').click(function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        $('.backdrop, #box').animate({
            'opacity': '.50'
        }, 300, 'linear');
        $('#box').animate({
            'opacity': '1.00'
        }, 300, 'linear');
        $('.backdrop, #box').css('display', 'block');
    });

    $('.lightbox2').click(function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        $('#box2').css({
            left: function () {
                return event.pageX - $(this).width();
            },
            top: function () {
                return event.pageY - $(this).height();
            }
        });
        $('.backdrop, #box2').animate({
            'opacity': '.50'
        }, 300, 'linear');
        $('#box2').animate({
            'opacity': '1.00'
        }, 300, 'linear');
        $('.backdrop, #box2').css('display', 'block');
    });
});

$('.backdrop, #box2').animate({
    'opacity': '.50'
}, 300, 'linear');
$('#box2').animate({
    'opacity': '1.00'
}, 300, 'linear');
$('.backdrop, #box2').css('display', 'block');


$('.close').click(function () {
    close_box();
});

$('.backdrop').click(function () {
    close_box();
});



function close_box() {
    $('.backdrop, #box, #box2').animate({
        'opacity': '0'
    }, 300, 'linear', function () {
        $('.backdrop, #box, #box2').css('display', 'none');
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your event bindings and animation functions are call before DOM elements load. So event bindings will not work.

I hope the following codes will work.

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $('.lightbox').click(function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        $('.backdrop, #box').animate({
            'opacity': '.50'
        }, 300, 'linear');
        $('#box').animate({
            'opacity': '1.00'
        }, 300, 'linear');
        $('.backdrop, #box').css('display', 'block');
    });

    $('.lightbox2').click(function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        $('#box2').css({
            left: function () {
                return event.pageX - $(this).width();
            },
            top: function () {
                return event.pageY - $(this).height();
            }
        });
        $('.backdrop, #box2').animate({
            'opacity': '.50'
        }, 300, 'linear');
        $('#box2').animate({
            'opacity': '1.00'
        }, 300, 'linear');
        $('.backdrop, #box2').css('display', 'block');
    });


    $('.backdrop, #box2').animate({
        'opacity': '.50'
    }, 300, 'linear');
    $('#box2').animate({
        'opacity': '1.00'
    }, 300, 'linear');
    $('.backdrop, #box2').css('display', 'block');

    // following lines are edited

    $('.close,.backdrop').click(close_box);

    function close_box() {
        $('.backdrop, #box, #box2').animate({
            'opacity': '0'
        }, 300, 'linear', function () {
            $('.backdrop, #box, #box2').css('display', 'none');
        });
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

so,

i browsed to your website, and with **Google Chrome Developer Tools (Console)** iv'e manually called `$('.lightbox').click()` and `close_box()` and it seems that it's working as excepted and no javascript exception were thrown.

however, i'm not sure that you even understand what's not working.

i highly suggest you to use Chrome browser with developer tools, it will make your life way easier regarding web development.

using this you could monitor javascript errors and debug your code line by line.

good luck

Comment: I have no idea what's not working. I am by no means a developer, I'm just tinkering with this because a project at work led me into it, and thus I have no idea on where to start with using the console part of the developer tools in chrome.

Comment: as i see it you must get dirty with the code in order to make it work as you like. all other ways are magic... 
good luck with that!